# checkstyle disable specific check

Tags: ant, checkstyle

I am using Ant and want to enable checkstyle for all packages,source, etc. Ideally it would have been as simple as adding a dependency on checkstyle on my existing build target but that broke the build because of violations. I don't want to do disabling using the comment style as that imply a change to the source files.

THE disabling I want to do is a specific type of check (e.g. trailing whitespace due to millions of violating lines in the existing codebase)

Is there a way to configure checkstyle to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable checks by adding or removing them from the Checkstyle configuration file that you specify when running the [Checkstyle Ant task](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html). Checkstyle runs exactly the checks that are present in the configuration XML (e.g. the [Sun Checks](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/code/ci/default/tree/sun_checks.xml)).

It is *not* possible to disable a check which is present in the configuration:

```xml
<module name="EmptyBlock">
    <property name="enabled" value="false" />   <!-- won't work -->
</module>
```

It is also not possible to tell Checkstyle to run "all checks except *EmptyBlock*", because there is no such thing as "all checks" - the set of available checks depends entirely on the configuration XML. However, it may be a good addition to the Checkstyle tool to support disabling of checks like shown above, as this would make life easier for people not using a configuration GUI.

If you don't want Checkstyle violations to fail the build, set the `failOnViolation` parameter of the Checkstyle Ant task to `false`. You can also use the `maxWarnings` and `maxErrors` parameters in order to set thresholds for how many warnings or errors to tolerate before the build should break.

Which violations are counted as errors and which as warnings depends on the `severity` property of the individual check in the Checkstyle configuration that you specify ([docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Severity)). The default severity is 'warning'.

Comment: Thanks, I guess then I'm more confused about the way configuration works then. Specifically, will specifying `<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
          <property name="severity" value="warning" />
        <module>
    </module>
</module>' mean checkstyle will run with only 3 checks, or does it mean checkstyle will run all enabled checks by default, but for the 3 listed, use any config values in the xml if they were specified? (e.g. warning severity)

Comment: It will only run the checks that you specify, in your example: three checks. 'warning' is the default severity.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. Which is really unfortunate as it would've been great to run _alll_ but one test by saying `<module name="EmptyBlock"><property name="enabled" value="false" /></module>`

Comment: Well, Checkstyle is only a framework for running checks, so there is no such thing as "all checks". But in your case, you could take the configuration you are running (e.g. the [Sun Checks](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/code/ci/default/tree/sun_checks.xml)), and remove *EmptyBlock* from it. That would give you the intended effect. When you switch to another configuration, just make sure that it, too, does not include *EmptyBlock*.

Comment: Thanks for checking in. If you would edit your answer from _Sure_ to _The short answer is no because there is no such thing as all checks_, I would accept the answer to my question. Being a 'framework for running checks' should not be an reason to not able to disable specific checks by an optional non-crashing configuration structure. That said, your answer will have answered my question and that Checkstyle is a great framework no doubt :)

Comment: @Lim I have consolidated all our comments into the answer text, including your example of an `enabled` property.